# **Decrease** size of interface font in Spyder Python IDE?

Tags: python, ide, spyder

I'm running Spyder IDE 4.2.0 on a widescreen 3440 x 1440 display.

ETA: This is on Windows 10.

The console text size is fine.

But the font size of the user interface windows is distractingly large, so much so it almost impacts the usability of settings windows. You can see examples below.

I've tried setting the high DPI scale to 1 (it cannot go below 1) and setting it to "Normal". I've tried resetting all the settings to default. The problem still persists.

Is there another solution?

[image: side console]

[image: preferences window]

Comment: is this Windows, Linux, Mac? Maybe it depends on system settings, not Spyder settings? Did you ask author of Spyder? Maybe they have own forum.

Comment: @furas Important point: this is on Windows 10. I edited the original question to add that information.

Comment: try Enable auto high DPI

Comment: @NaN No difference.

Comment: @furas Also, my native Windows 10 DPI settings are set at 100% (1:1, so no magnification)

Comment: I have the exact same problem on a 4K monitor at 100%, Windows 11, and Spyder 5.5.1, and none of the settings in Spyder make a differences.  On Github this problem has been open for years, so unfortunately the only solution seems to be a different IDE.

Answer (score 0):

In the menu please go to 'Tools' then 'Preferences'. Then go to the settings for 'Application'. Change the Screen resolution from 'Enable auto high DPI scaling' to 'Normal'.

For me, this solved the problem (after a restart of spyder), although I have to add that I have spyder version 5.0 and not 4.2 (Windows 10).